# deleting rows in linux

Tags: python, linux, bash, file-io

I have a number of huge delimited text files containing information logged by date. Some of the files overlap slightly with each other by date (which I don't want since it leads to duplicates). I know what the overlapping dates are so I want to be able to go through some of the files and delete each of the rows that contains those specified dates.

I know how to do this in python (rewriting each of the lines I want) but because of the size of the files (each is a few GBs) I was wondering if it would be a lot faster to do this through linux?

The text files will be sorted by date, earliest to latest, and the dates I need to delete are always going to be in the beginning of the file so I can search until I hit a row that has a date right after the ones I want to delete and write out the rest of the file to another file (or delete all the contents above).

Comment: Linux is an OS not a programming language.

Comment: it's not clear what "do this through linux" means.  what operating system do you run python on?

Comment: Oh I meant doing it using the command line on a linux server. Does that make sense?

Comment: “It's hard to attach a trailer to the tow-hitch on my car. I was going to use a pry bar. Would this be easier with a Maserati?”

Comment: you're too funny...let me rephrase: what would be the way of doing this that has the shortest runtime

Comment: Now that I have a reasonable idea what you want, I've supplied a reasonably complete solution that uses the usual text mashing tools on *Linux*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it's quite expensive to remove data from the beginning or the middle of a file. However, it is far cheaper to append data to a file, or to remove data from the end of a file.

In this case, let's assume that we have a file:

```
import io
fd = io.FileIO('foo.txt', 'r+')
```

Let's do some work to determine the offset where the file starts overlapping with `bar.txt`.

```
# You do some work...
offset = compute_overlap_offset()
```

Now, let's truncate `foo.txt` so that there is no overlap any more.

```
fd.truncate(offset)
```

Comment: So I can have the file sorted from latest to earliest and then remove the last n lines. Does truncate take the size of the file as an argument? How could I determine what size the portion I want is?

Comment: Nice idea, hadn't thought of that. However, if you are processing things one file at a time, line by line, you might not know in advance if the next file might start with ending portion of current file. So this wouldn't be possible in every scenario. But it seems the original poster has all these files available from the beginning, so this can be done.

Comment: Yeah I have all the files and know what exact dates the overlaps are. Can I use `readlines` to go through the file until I get to the dates I need removed and then use `tell()` to calculate the offset and use `truncate` to get rid of those lines (assuming I have the dates I don't want at the end of the file)?

Answer (score 0):

There are various command line applications that would be able to accomplish this when working together. For example, you could `cat` all the files one after another, `grep -v` the patterns you don't want, redirecting `>>` to a new file. In effect this is doing the same thing as your Python script would do, because every line of every file must be copied (except the duplicates). It might be faster than Python, though, because those tools are written in C.

Comment: This is a matter of tools rather than OS.

Comment: Yes. The person who asked the question clarified in the comment that he wanted to know if, and how, it could be done using command line tools on Linux.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to only apply grep -v to a certain column? Another column in the files also has a date but I want to ignore that when determining what lines to get rid of.

Comment: You can write your regular expression in a way that matches only the column you want.

Comment: @StSh: Alternatively, consider using `awk`, which is optimized for parsing lines into columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to see the last lines of a particular file:

```
$ tail file
```

Get the final date in there from that, then use grep to find the line number in another file of the line that matches that date:

```
$ grep -n 2012-10-23 nextfile
100234: 2012-10-23 etc whatever
```

Now tail out the lines following that into a new file:

```
$ tail -n +100235 nextfile >nextfile_truncated
```

Note that I took the output line number from the grep output and incremented it by one in the last tail operation to get everything after the matching line.

Now you can compare the original and truncated versions of the file (e.g. with diff), and once satisfied delete the original.

Answer (score 0):

This is the situation, as near as I can deduce:

- You have two large log files: `file1.log` and `file2.log`
- The logs contain entries in chronological order: `file1.log` precedes `file2.log`
- An number of entries appear at the end of `file1.log` and the start of `file2.log`

*If* these log files have high-resolution timestamps or otherwise have distinct lines (like most log files on Linux), all you have to do is find the first occurrence of the *last* line of `file1.log` in `file2.log`: this gives you the size of the repeated block of lines, which you can then truncate from `file1.log`.

I expect that this is the fastest way to do it with the usual *nix utilities (searching the start, truncating rather than trying to remove the beginning, etc.).

The following works in my tests, but does not handle any special cases (like `file1`.log being very small, etc.)

```
#!/bin/bash

test_mode=false

file1="$1"
file2="$2"

# Last line of file1:
last=$(tail -1 "$file1")

# Use fgrep because we want an exact match and don't need regexes.
# Bug out after the first match (-m1), return the byte offset (-b),
# and extract this number from the match with cut:
nb=$(fgrep -bm1 "$last" "$file2" | cut -d: -f1)

# 'nb' now is the byte offset to the *start* of 'last' in file2; the
# *total* size of the repeated lines *includes* last itself:
ln=$(echo "$last"|wc -c)
nb=$(( $nb + $ln ))

# The size of file1 less the repeated lines is:
sz=$(( $(stat -c%s "$file1") - $nb ))

# Down to business!
if [ $test_mode == 'false' ]; then
    # Hack the end off file1:
    truncate -s $sz "$file1"
else
    echo "New size of '$file1' would be $sz bytes"
    dd if="$file1" bs=1 skip=$sz count=$ln
fi
```

Shell I used for synthetic example (after copying a 19000-ish kernel log file):

```
$ rm -f xa[a-z] && split -l 10000 kern.log && tail -n1 xaa && ls -l xaa && head -n100 xab >> xaa
```

Comment: @StSh: Good luck with it. I was surprised how well it worked (worked first time) on my synthetic data, although it's much smaller than yours. Let me know how it works out for you: I'd be interested to know if it works well with very large files (in theory, it should).